# detect USB C/ Thunderbolt 3 connection in event viewer?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, thunderbolt, event-viewer, usb-c

I have recently made a simple PowerShell script that upon connection of a PnP device checks whether a "razer naga" mouse is connected and runs the synapse software. Upon disconnection of the device, the script runs again and closes the software.

To make this work I enabled logging of DriverFrameworks-UserMode in Event Viewer, and liked the script that does the checking to event 2101 (PnP or Power Management operation to a particular device).

I would now like to do the same for my monitor (a script that checks whether the monitor is connected on an event, and opens/closes the monitor manager software accordingly). But the monitor is connected through usb c (on the Thuderbolt 3 port of my laptop - XPS 9560), and upon connection/disconnection, no new events are listed in the same directory (Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational) in event viewer.

Could you please help me identify where USB C/ TB3 connection events are logged?